# OpenCV findcontours() crash

Tags: opencv

```
Cow browncow;

vector <Cow> Cows;

Mat temp;
threshold.copyTo(temp);

vector< vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

I'm making some code that needs to find the contours in a image, and my code breaks. My code breaks on the findContours(); function call and my debugger says 
"An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal." any ideas why this is?

Comment: May be u need to convert your image into Gray or single channel.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Having the same one atm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CV_RETR_TREE instead of CV_RETR_CCOMP. If it doesn't help I had once fixed findContours() with just switching to release mode of the build. Or look at Sagar's comment.

Answer (score -2):

same error with me you can just copy 
vector< vector > contours;
vector hierarchy;**
this and make these variables global outside your function and change the debug mode with release mode hope it will work...